# Add a column with a fix value into a list with multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple lists inside a main list that looks like following:

```
print(result_list)

[      rating  \
0   3 stars
1   3 stars   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
place
0   L’Osteria
1   Shiva,

rating  \
0   5 stars
1   4 stars
2   3 stars
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               place  
0   Bio Bakery
1   Nova Era Bakery
2   Panino Italiano
]
```

When typing `type(result_list[0])` it will return `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

I want to add a third column named "category". This column should have a fix value assigned such as “Restaurant” or “Bakery”. The output should look like following:

```
[      rating  \
2   3 stars
3   3 stars   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
place
2   L’Osteria
3   Shiva

category
0   Restaurant
1   Restaurant,


rating  \
3   5 stars
4   4 stars
5   3 stars
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
place  
3   Bio Bakery
4   Nova Era Bakery
5   Panino Italiano

category
0   Bakery
1   Bakery


]
```

So far I have tried among other things this, but it is not working.

```
lista = ['Restaurant','Bakery']

for i,e in enumerate(result_list):
    #print('index:',i)
    result_list.append(lista[i])
```

I am missing the logic here. Please help!

---

Comment: Is that a list of dataframes? You need to use pandas methods to add to them.

Comment: If you want to add a column, you need to add that to `e`, not `result_list`.

Comment: What does `type(result_list[0])` show?

Comment: is this pandas?

Comment: @Barmar But how? If I transform it into a dataframe I wont be able to identify where the categories are. As you see I have a fix value per list. I have update the comment, you can see the output of result_list[0] above

Comment: @Barmar I mean if I do this -> pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(result_list)) I will have a dataframe will all values. But then it is impossible to identify which place belong to which category. That is the reason why I believe I need to add the column before

Comment: I askjed for the type of it, not the value. But that doesn't look like what you showed in `print(result_list)`. Where did the df with the `place` column go? And where did the `review` column come from?

Comment: I never said you should transform it into a dataframe. It looks like the elements are already dataframes. So you should do something like `result_list[i]["new_column"] = values`

Comment: Sorry about that. The original data has other column names. I just updated it

Comment: @Barmar When I write -> type(result_list) , it returns "list" as output

Comment: `type(result_list[0])`

Comment: @Barmar type(result_list[0]) -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are pandas dataframes. So just add the new column to each df.

```
for df, category in zip(result_list, lista):
    df['Category'] = category
```

Comment: That worked, thank you @Barmar! I also figured that this code is also returning the same results: 

for i,df in enumerate(result_list):
    for column in lista:
        df['place'] = lista[i]